# GFCI keeps tripping after several minutes of gas range running

Tags: electrical, gfci, range

I have an odd issue:

My new(ish) gas range is on a 20 amp GFCI and has been working fine for 4-5 months. Recently, (after a self clean cycle, though not sure it matters) it has been tripping the GFCI every 5 or so minutes it runs while heating.
Notes so far:

- GFCI was replaced just to be sure, didn't help.
- Inline ammeter shows draw at ~10-11 amps, so overload is not an issue (nothing else on GFCI was running). Also tried running larger (13 amp) loads and it doesn't trip.

My inclination is that something is damaged with the oven, possibly that it damaged itself during the high heat cycle. Repair company sent out by manufacturer says to get an electrician out, though they couldn't really explain why this would be the issue and only check they did was plug into inline ammeter.

Any ideas what might be the issue? Not really interested in paying an electrician when I'm quite certain the issue is with the range. Anything I may be missing?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like the GFCI is working correctly.  The heat heat probably did damage some wires and you now have a ground fault.  This might be a defect with the oven and high heat, or you just got unlucky.  Do have it checked out.

Comment: Run an extension cord from another GFCI outlet and make sure it's a problem with the oven

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds to me like there is a thermal expansion issue causing something energized to come in contact with a ground connection.

I'd suggest that you ask the manufacturer to send out a *qualified* technician to actually go over the oven itself looking for loose connections, wires with frayed insulation, loose or missing insulation in the oven, or other issues.

While an electrician may be able to find wiring that's in poor shape, someone who should be trained on the actual piece of equipment <s>would</s> *should* know where something has gone missing or isn't installed as it should be and would be better qualified to assess the oven.

The fact that this happened after a self-clean (where the oven usually heats to over 500°F) *might* be an indication that the failure is related to the extra high temp, especially if this was the *first* self-clean. In any case, if the oven is new (you indicate 5-6 months), it should be covered by warranty.

Comment: Eggsactly on target. The technician they sent is incompetent, and they want you to waste money on an electrician rather than having a competent technician fix the problem caused by the self-clean melting something that should not have been in a position to melt.